# Object initialization problem - not null inside function but is null when I exit function

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have code like this ( I have used Dojo for classes ):

```
var current_div=null;
var current_element=null;
var elements_container=null;
var status_container=null;

function main(){
    //alert(status_container==null);
    load_status_system();
    //alert(status_container==null);
    load_ring_topology();
    //alert(status_container==null);
}
```

inside load_status_system I set function load_status_system() {

```
 dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "dynamic/status-system.json",
        handleAs: "json",
        load: function(obj) {
            status_container=new STATUS_CONTAINER(obj);
            alert(status_container==null);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('error during loading status-system.json');
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is that I get status_container null outside function but inside function it is not null. What is wrong with this code ? How to initialize status_container not to be null outside the function ?

Comment: "_I get status_container null outside function_"...what function?
"_but inside function it is different null_"...different null? There is no such thing as a different null...can you elaborate? "_How to initialize status_container not to be null outside the function_", again, what function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scoping seems to be fine.  I think you’re wrestling with the asynchronous nature of Ajax calls.

As posted, the order of execution of your code is as follows:

1. function `main`
2. `main` => `load_status_system()`
3. `load_status_system` => `dojo.xhrGet`
4. `main` => `load_ring_topology()`
5. function `main` is done and exits (`status_container` is still `null`)
6. `dojo.xhrGet` receives its response, calls `load()`
7. `load` => fills `status_container`
8. `load` alerts the new `status_container` and exits.
9. your code is done running

The solution to your problem would be to tell `xhrGet` to do its call **synchronously**.  I’ve never used Dojo, so I don’t know how to do that. Usually it’s done by setting the `async` property of the XHR object to `false`.

Comment: Now that I understand the issue he is having, I fully agree with this. Basically, if `load_ring_topology()` can only be called after `dojo.xhrGet` returns, you must put that in a callback. +1

Comment: One thing, however, I would caution the use of synchronous xhr requests. There is a reason why many javascript libraries do not expose this option as it leads to slow/unresponsive javascript applications when used frequently

Comment: True enough.  The better solution is to put `load_ring_topology` in the `load` callback function.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a scoping issue. I would try accessing status_container as `window.status_container` from within the XHR callback

Answer (score 0):

Use dojo.hitch() to specify the scope in which the function will run.